# Python dynamic class with different class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, metaclass

I have a class definition roughly like:

```
Class X(metaclass=XMetaClass):
    fields = []

    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr
        # Use fields here
```

Now I want to create instances of X but with different `fields` each time. I think the following should work, but it isn't.

```
import types
types.new_class(
    name="X",
    bases=(X,),
    exec_body=lambda ns: ns.update({"fields": fields}),
)
```

To my understanding this should set the class variable `fields` and return the class `X` but it doesn't.

This one works but I think it's not good:

```
x_class = X
x_class.fields = [...]
x = x_class()
```

Now `x` instance will have the correct `fields`.

Comment: If you want to create instances of X but with different fields each time, shouldn’t fields just be a property of the instance?

Comment: @Mark It is, but it's a 3rd party library so I can't change that.